# C# proper way to loop through a float

Tags: c#

I am looping through a function that looks like this:

```
Y=exp(-0.04*(x-13.25)^(2))*300
```

Let's say I want to get `Y`for every value of `x` between 3.3454 and 20.3458 for every `0.1 interval`

I would do this:

```
for (float i=3.3454;i<20.3458;i=+.1)
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: Your left parenthesis is not in the right place.  I assume that is not part of your question?

Comment: `for (float i=3.3454;i<=20.3458;i=+.1)`: make sure your condition is set to `<=` not just `<'.

Comment: @Ryan: given these are floats, I'm not sure if that helps or hurts. In the end you could have i actually be greater than 20.3458. I don't know if the limits are fixed or variable nor if 20.3458 will be particularly problematic at all, but I think it a good idea to point out.

Comment: @ryan thank you. also do you know how to code this in c# Y=exp(-0.04*(x-13.25)^(2))*300

Comment: @Ryan the <= isn't necessary based on the math, it would run for 20.3454 and then go over. The end value and step make it not necessary. But it doesn't hurt either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off, and some of the math functions you want to use will only work on doubles.

```
double y;
for(double x=3.3454; x<20.3458; x += .1) {
    y = Math.Exp(-0.04D * Math.Pow((x- 13.25D), 2D)) * 300;
    // do something with y
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you add 0.1 each loop, you're going to end up with cumulative errors. It is not possible to precisely store 0.1 as a floating point number, and when you repeatedly add 0.1F/D, you'll start noticing drift. If you really want to get as close as possible, use integers for the loop then divide your integer values to calculate your floats.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the "F". Without which you'll get a compile error

> literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type 'float';
>   use an 'F' suffix to create a literal
>   of this type

```
for (float i = 3.3454F; i < 20.3458; i += .1F)
```

Also this is kinda dangerous, because the increment may not result in a change
For example

```
        float f;
        f = float.MinValue;
        f += .1F;

        Console.WriteLine(f == float.MinValue);
```

Outputs True.

This is because a float is an approximation.

Comment: gah, beat me to it. anyway link: (see 'Literals') http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change it to this

```
for (float i=3.3454;i<=20.3458;i+=0.1)
```

parenthesis need to be after the `for` keyword ;)
also you had `i=+.1` which is not how you would increase a variable and would create a syntax error

Comment: thank you. also do you know how to code this in c# Y=exp(-0.04*(x-13.25)^(2))*300

Comment: yes, you would use Math.Exp you can find more information on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.exp.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I used a stack, but you could use anything to store the values:

```
        Stack YStack = new Stack();
        for(float x = 3.3454F; x < 20.3458F; x += .1F)
        {
            YStack.Push(Math.Exp(-0.04*Math.Pow(x-13.25,(2)))*300)
        }
        return YStack.ToArray();
```